# MVC Route register

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

I have various routes registered, and have just added the following to the top of my collection:

```
routes.MapRoute("EmployeesUnassign", "Terminals_Employees/UnAssignEmployee/{employeeId}/{datagroupId}", new { controller = "Terminals_Employees", action = "UnAssignEmployee" });
routes.MapRoute("Employees", "Terminals_Employees/{id}", new { controller = "Terminals_Employees", action = "Index" });
```

If I try to go to `/Terminals_Employees/UnAssignEmployee/1/2`

I get the following error:

```
The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Index(Int32)' in 'Terminals_Employees.Controllers.Terminals_Employees'
```

If I remove these routes then all is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ive realised the problem, going to the url worked fine, but I was psoting them through ajax, which of course means the values were not part of the url but contained in the headers.

Comment: the route should be like this `new { controller = "Terminals_Employees", action = "UnAssignEmployee",
                     employeeId = UrlParameter.Optional,
                     datagroupId = UrlParameter.Optional`